# 'not-responding' tag is not required

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tags, burninate-request

I just happen to come across [not-responding](/questions/tagged/not-responding) tag on SO. Which I think is not a correct and meaningful tag.

It should probably be deleted.

Comment: Definitely looks like a meta-tag to me, yes.

Comment: I hate tags without a wiki summary.

Comment: Hey, it's totally legit. I will name my programming language thus.

Comment: @AustinHenley and I hate tags that no reasonable person would be expected to search on or subscribe to.

Comment: @Martijn Please can you tell me how 'meta-tags' tag is related with this? I am probably misunderstanding this.

Comment: @mtk: The `not-responding` tag cannot stand on it's own. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/ as well. This is a meta tag as it cannot ever be applied to a post alone without other tags.

Comment: @Martijn Thanks for the explanation. I really mis-interpreted the word 'meta-tags'.